# Is there a way to enable traffic logs and unhandled requests logging on Mockintosh startup

Tags: mocking

[Mockintosh](https://mockintosh.io/Management.html) allows to switch on `Traffic Logs` and `Unhandled Requests` logging in UI or via rest API.

I want to have these options enabled already when starting as part of `docker-compose` config.

E.g to set them via environment variables.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Mockintosh management docs](https://mockintosh.io/Management.html), you can use curl to enable it.

curl -X POST -F 'enable=true' /traffic-log

Just add an additional command to your .yml and it should work.